# Initial Condition of Costate equation of Minimum Time Problem (Optimal Control)

Tags: dynamical-systems, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

Consider $$\dot{x}=\begin{bmatrix}0.1 & 1\\ 0 & 0.1\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}u$$ 
with $x(0)=[1 \ \ \ \ 1]'$ and $x(T)=[0 \ \ \ \ 0]'$. Consider the minimum-time problem with fixed final state and free final time $$J(0) = \int_0^T 1 dt$$

To solve this problem,

1. Hamiltonian: $$H=1+\lambda_1(0.1x_1+x_2)+\lambda_2(0.1x_2+u)$$
2. Find costate equations:  $$\begin{cases}-\dot{\lambda}_1=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_1}=0.1\lambda_1 \\ -\dot{\lambda}_2=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_2}=\lambda_1+0.1\lambda_2 \end{cases}$$
3. Solve costate equations
    $$\begin{cases} \lambda_1(t)=C e^{-0.1(T-t)} \\ \lambda_2(t)=(C_1-Ct) e^{-0.1(T-t)}  \end{cases}$$

> My question is how to find the initial condition of costate equation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the entire end state is given you need to solve for the initial conditions of the co-states such that it results in $x(T)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^\top$. Your system is linear and might have an algebraic solution, however those don't exist in general for nonlinear systems and one would have to use method like the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method).

Your current problem formulation is, I assume, not complete and it should also include constraints on $u$. Namely the "optimal" input $u^*$ can be found by solving

$$
u^* = \arg \min_u H(x,u,\lambda).
$$

For example if the input is constraint by $|u|<1$ your problem has the solution

$$
u^* = -\text{sgn}(\lambda_2).
$$

Using $u=u^*$ on the system yields a given trajectory for a given initial condition for the co-states. Every initial condition for the co-states will drive the system the to the corresponding end state, while minimizing the cost function. However, only one initial condition for the co-states will yield the desired end state.